# The clique number ($\omega $) of a graph G is the largest integer k such that K_k is a subgraph of G

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Prove that if G $\cong$  H then $\omega(G)=\omega(H)$.

So this makes sense. But how do I go about proving it? I understand if two graphs are isomorphic then they are essentially the same and that their clique number would be equal. But how do I prove it?

Comment: Consider an isomorphism then look at what the image of a clique under the isomorphism is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed this is intuitively obvious: isomorphisms merely change the vertex label, so have no effect on clique sizes.  But, to do it formally, let $\varphi$ denote an isomorphism, and we prove:

1. If $V$ is a set of vertices of $G$ that induces a clique, then $\varphi(V)=\{\varphi(v):v \in V\}$ induces a clique in $H$ (i.e., we check that if $x,y \in V$ then there is an edge between $\varphi(x)$ and $\varphi(y)$ in $H$).

This shows that a maximum sized clique in $H$ is at least as large as that of $G$.  The claim then follows since $\varphi^{-1}$ is an isomorphism from $H$ to $G$.